# AutoComplete text box with text value and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want auto complete text box with text and id .I used the following code for auto complete in my application

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $auto=$.noConflict();
$auto(document).ready(function(){    
    var data3 = ['niju','vivek','anil','Anil'];
    $auto("#employee").autocomplete(data3);

  });
</script>

<input   type="text" name="employee" id="employee" value="" class="inp-form">
```

In this code we faced one drawback .There can be duplicate entry is possible since the same values as been repeated .

How to get id value instead of text label ?

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Demo [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/5c6ut/2/)

Comment: Try this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/jquery-ui-autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

You can try with a source define like : `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`.
See documentation here : [autocomplete#option-source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

In your case it would be something like :
`var data3 = [{label: 'niju', value: 1},{label : 'vivek', value : 2}, ...];
$auto("#employee").autocomplete({source: data3});`

Comment: i tried following one but it did`t work
                                                              var data3=[{label: 'niju', value: 1},{label : 'vivek', value : 2}];

Comment: When I test on my part, autocomplete correctly select the right value to use in the input : When tapping `an`, autocomplete display me two solution (`anil` and `Anil`), and on selecting one of them, the correct value (3 or 4 in my example) fill the textfield.